# .NET Core 5/6 console app as a simple exe is large

Tags: c#, .net

Because I'm old-fashioned I like to build a .NET console app (or WPF for that matter) as a single .exe file and copy it to a folder in my PATH (e.g. %USERPROFILE%\Bin). Using VS2022 with .NET Framework 4.8, and assuming it's installed on the target, a simple x64 HelloWorld generates a 4,608-byte exe. I then copy it to Bin, for example with a post-build step.

But I thought I'd try Core 5 (and 6) just because it feels like the right thing, and publish direct to Bin, but the smallest exe I can get using the standard tools is 154,536 bytes. I realize the internal mechanism is different, but why is there so much extra stuff?

I used dotnet publish with:

--runtime win-x64 --configuration Release -p:PublishSingleFile=true --self-contained=false -p:PublishReadyToRun=false
or the equivalent IDE settings.

and I know "disk" storage is very cheap, but I still get annoyed at the apparent waste. Am I missing something?

Comment: *"a simple x64 HelloWorld generates a 4,608-byte exe"* - you're forgetting about the multi-MB installation that is .NET Framework 4.8. When you build a .NET Core single EXE file, it *includes the .NET Core runtime* instead of depending on a shared installation somewhere.

Comment: It is because of the host, required by any VM language.  Much like Java (java.exe), Python (python.exe), the host acts as the glue between the OS and the VM language.  Microsoft tried very hard to get .NET programmers used to dotnet.exe, but it didn't work.  .NET 4.x has a host as well, c:\windows\system32\mscor*.dll, takes 479,816 bytes.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `--self-contained false`  (i.e. without the `=`)? Or just straight up `--no-self-contained`.

Comment: @madreflection: I think I see what you are saying. What I don't get is: when using the Framework, the app can find the runtime installed in a known location. When built with Core, why can't the app similarly find the Core runtime in a known location, since I have indicated that the target machine (in this simple case, the same PC I'm developing on) has the required dependencies. To Etienne de Martel, my error reading the doc, but it turns out to work with or without =.

Comment: About 150 kB -meaning you can easily have a million apps on your computer. What is the problem?

Comment: @PoulBak: Point taken: as I said, I'm old-fashioned (I learned to care about memory and disk in 1970 and it's hard to shake those early experiences). But also it's just a few years ago that a bug landed on my plate complaining that I had made a change that added _one_ 4K IOPS to a mobile app... Still. I think I got my answers. Thanks, all.